# Can firestore with enabled persistence be used with service worker?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore, service-worker, angular-service-worker

**Background:**
I have encountered a problem while working on a project that uses angularfire2 v5 and Angular v5. The problem is that I want to use service worker and firestore with enabled persistence for offline support. However, service worker is not being installed. My presumption is that enabled persistence for firestore causes service worker to not be installed.

**Question:**
Can firestore with enabled persistence be used with service worker?

Comment: can you show your code or error logs? Service workers can indeed be used alongside persistent Firestore.

Comment: No errors are present. The problem is that sometimes it takes several reloads (~20) or time to pass for a service worker to be registered. That to me is an unexpected behaviour.

In terms of code it is a usual pattern of using enabled persistence and registering service worker in production build only which is specified in app.module

I also consider putting the registrations inside main.ts file and register service worker on boostrap. I think that might solve the problem since I have seen people reporting similar problem. However, that feels more like a hack to me than actual solution.

Comment: Sorry but I still can't tell what the specific issue is without a demo or more information :/ But to answer the main question - **Yes, Firestore with enabled persistence can be used with service worker**. Best of luck

Comment: This is a very good question that carries no answer yet! Was wondering the same thing myself. Any answers?

Answer (score 2):

I struggled to obtain the same result lately, and I managed to have it working as expected. Everything worked fine after I rearranged `imports` in `app.module.ts` to look like this:

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
AngularFirestoreModule.enablePersistence(),
```

My versions:

```
"@angular/core": "~7.1.0",
"@angular/fire": "^5.1.1",
"@angular/cli": "~7.1.4"
```